# Using an ArrayFormula to expand Countifs both rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Problem:
I am trying to make a dynamic arrayformula countifs that will automatically expand with new rows and columns. The criteria rows and headers are auto populated by unique formulas.

What I have so far:
Headers are from G3:3 (will expand various columns with new data)
Criteria Rows start at A4:A and go down from there (will expand various rows with new data)
Current working formula
`={ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!$B$3:$B,INDIRECT("$A4:$A" & 'Settings (Do Not Modify)'!$B$1+3),'True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!$C$3:$C,G$3)); ""; SUM(ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!$B$3:$B,INDIRECT("$A4:$A" & 'Settings (Do Not Modify)'!$B$1+3),'True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!$C$3:$C,G$3)))}`
The problem with this formula is I have to copy and paste this into each cell under the header (row 4) to make it count.

I've tried modifying G$3 to G$3:3 but I am getting an error of Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size.
Image below is a screenshot sorry can't share the live sheet. 
[image: screenshot of google sheet]

The would like to place the formula in the red cell on the YTD Tracker sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zdm8s-qby7SPRYelLAHmhN46uMROGKhRw8GtfI5nOYg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried using sumproduct like below and getting a similar issue like the countifs
`=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT(('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!$B$3:$B = A4:A12)*('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!$C$3:$C = G3:M3)))`
Error: Array arguments to EQ are of different size

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls with some fake data

Comment: @player0 I've share a sheet in the original post

Comment: I had a look at your sheet and cant rly tell what are you after. it looks different from the picture, it has some REF errors and the sample is not rly self-explanatory. can you explain it to me in more detail?

Comment: @player0 Ignore columns B-F those work fine on the working spreadsheet. 
The data on the True Rejections are imported from another spreadsheet (that I don't have access to) and gets updated monthly. With those monthly updates it's possible that new users are added with new issues. My goal is to have a single countifs that can expand both down and right.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A4:A"&COUNTA(A4:A)+2), 
 QUERY(QUERY('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!A3:C, 
 "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot C"), "offset 1", 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&
 COUNTUNIQUE('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!C3:C)+1))), 0))*1)
```

[image: 0]

---

without zeros:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("A4:A"&COUNTA(A4:A)+2), 
 QUERY(QUERY('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!A3:C, 
 "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot C"), "offset 1", 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A2:A"&
 COUNTUNIQUE('True Rejections (Do Not Modify)'!C3:C)+1))), 0)))
```

Comment: I looked at both formulas that you added to my sheet and they both are what I'm looking for. I did end up going with the one without zeros. Can you modify your answer to include both formulas incase someone else needs the same thing. Thanks.